# Div below the screen

Tags: html, css, wordpress, widget, sidebar

I'm making a wordpress website with custom template. 
I made two custom sidebar areas, which are intendet to be used for ads (left and right from the main website container).
The left one is working almost fine (I wanted to make them both 100vh or at least with 10% top margin, which didn't worked, but it's not that important), but the right one is been shown below the screen. I checked several times the code of the right one is the same as the left one without the right positioning.
The code which i used is the following:

functions.php

```
register_sidebar(array(
    'name'=> 'Ads Sidebar Background Left',
    'id' => 'ads-sidebar-back-left',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="ads-sidebar-back-left-css">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
));

register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Ads Sidebar Background Right',
    'id' => 'ads-sidebar-back-right',
    'before_widget' => '<div class="ads-sidebar-back-right-css">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
 ));
```

header.php

```
<div id="ads-sidebar-back-left" class="ads-sidebar-back-left-css" role="complementary">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Ads Sidebar Background Left' ); ?>
</div>

<div id="ads-sidebar-back-right" class="ads-sidebar-back-right-css" role="complementary">
<?php dynamic_sidebar( 'Ads Sidebar Background Right' ); ?>
</div>
```

style.css

```
div.ads-sidebar-back-left-css {

height:100%;
position:absolulte;
top: 10%;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
width: 30%;

}

.ads-sidebar-back-left-css img{

height: 100vh;
}

div.ads-sidebar-back-right-css {

height:100%;
position:absolulte;
float: right;
right:5px;
overflow:hidden;
z-index:1000;
width: 30%;
}

.ads-sidebar-back-right-css img{

height: 100vh;
}
```

After that i'm adding ad widgets into them, with the corresponding size and ad script.

When i tried to follow the divs I saw that the right one have some divs not generated or the output from tormus div tool is:

```
<div class="background-cover">
  |<div id="ads-sidebar-back-left" class="ads-sidebar-back-left-css" role="complementary">
  |       |<div id="ads300_600-widget-4" class="ads300-600">
  |       |       |<div class="ad-cell">
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
  |<div id="ads-sidebar-back-right" class="ads-sidebar-back-right-css" role="complementary">
  |       |<div class="ads-sidebar-back-right-css">
  |       |       |<div class="ads300-600">
  |       |       |       |<div class="ad-cell">
  |       |       |       |</div>
  |       |       |</div>
  |       |</div>
  |</div>
```

I can't understand why the left one have different frontend divs, as I made both of the areas identical.

From W3.org validator I have:

```
Info: The Content-Type was text/html. Using the HTML parser.
Info: Using the schema for HTML with SVG 1.1, MathML 3.0, RDFa 1.1, and ITS 2.0 support.
Error: Duplicate attribute prefix.
At line 2, column 57
.me/ns#" prefix="og: http://og
Error: A meta element with an http-equiv attribute whose value is X-UA-Compatible must have a content attribute with the value IE=edge.
From line 61, column 1; to line 61, column 64
</script>↩<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />↩<meta
Error: End tag div seen, but there were open elements.
From line 330, column 3; to line 330, column 8
</div>  ↩       </div>  ↩           <
Error: Unclosed element nav.
From line 267, column 10; to line 267, column 54
↩                                   <nav id="main-nav" class="fade-in animated2">↩              <
Error: Stray end tag nav.
From line 331, column 4; to line 331, column 9
/div>   ↩           </nav><!-- .
Error: The align attribute on the div element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 333, column 3; to line 333, column 35
er /-->↩        <div class="clear" align="right"><span
Warning: Empty heading.
From line 1281, column 113; to line 1281, column 116
dget-top"><h4>      </h
Error: The scrolling attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 1283, column 5; to line 1283, column 366
box">↩              <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?   href=https://www.facebook.com/Peoples.Repub…order="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:250px;" allowTransparency="true"> </ifra
Error: The frameborder attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 1283, column 5; to line 1283, column 366
box">↩              <iframe  src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/Peoples.Repub…order="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:250px;" allowTransparency="true"></ifra
Error: The allowtransparency attribute on the iframe element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 1283, column 5; to line 1283, column 366
box">↩              <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/likebox.php?href=https://www.facebook.com/Peoples.Repub…order="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:300px; height:250px;" allowTransparency="true"></ifra
Error: The align attribute on the div element is obsolete. Use CSS instead.
From line 1409, column 1; to line 1409, column 68
</script>↩<div align="center"  style=" text-align:center; position:relative;"><span
```

None of them is related to the two areas.

How to align the right sidebar area in the right of the website and how to make them both 100vh?

Regards,
Ivan

Comment: add jsfiddle with pure html/css/js

Comment: I'm not sure that jsfiddle have the wordpress functions as `register_sidebar`,  but I'll try

Comment: We don't need wordpress function, we need a peace of  code which have an  issue

Comment: But in my understanding the issue is with the generated divs from the up mentioned function. As you can see the second `ads300-600` div have no id generated by the function. And there is `ads-sidebar-back-right-css` div which is not present in the first one. I can't strip the code from the function as the awnser of that won't surve me no purpose.

Comment: But what the problem in css? If you sure, that problem in wordpress please change the question and make it more clear

Comment: Thank you for the remark. I modified the question.

Comment: If the problem is caused by the dynamic_sidebar function, then please show that function. According to the validator output, you apparently have some end tags exchanged.

Comment: This is one of the wordpress build-in functions. You can read more about it here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar

Comment: The function itself is: `function dynamic_sidebar($index = 1) {
         global $wp_registered_sidebars, $wp_registered_widgets;
 
         if ( is_int($index) ) {
                 $index = "sidebar-$index";
         } else {
                 $index = sanitize_title($index);
                 foreach ( (array) $wp_registered_sidebars as $key => $value ) {
                         if ( sanitize_title($value['name']) == $index ) {
                                 $index = $key;
                                 break;
                         }
                 }
         }`